# ListView causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

This is my first Android app, i am trying to put a listview on and i have followed numerous tutorials but i always get the same result, a crash upon starting the app.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mattigins.mediacenter.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/View01"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_trans_box" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view1"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_trans_box" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View01" >

</ListView>
```

Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List1);
        String[] test_items = {"1","2","3","4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> test_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test_items);
        listView.setAdapter(test_adapter);

}
```

Comment: logcat please... and whats simple_list_item_1?

Comment: are you using the provided XML as layout? because you don't have `R.id.container`..if your list is in the fragment, you should move the code to your fragment's `onCreateView`

Comment: @yogx : the `android.R.layout` should tell you what it is...

Comment: Just as an advice, don't capitalize your ids in your xml.

Comment: Looking at this `tools:context="com.mattigins.mediacenter.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"` gives a clue it belongs to the fragment layout although this has nothing to with the crash. posting stacktrace will confirm

Comment: Also, when stating that you receive an Exception, please post the stack and indicate where is happened on your code (we dont have line numbers). Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `ListView` belongs to the `Fragment` layout. Looking at

In `onCreateView` of `Fragment`.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.List1);
String[] test_items = {"1","2","3","4"};
ArrayAdapter<String> test_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test_items);
listView.setAdapter(test_adapter);
```